# Content-Aware option not showing on photoshop cs3

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

I want to remove unwanted images from my main image using photoshop CSS3. I found content-aware technique to deal with issue. However when I am opening fill option from edit menu its not showing content-aware option in my dropdown box.

I am using Photoshop CS3.

How can I deal with issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I remember correctly content aware fill was added to Photoshop in version CS5 (and improved in CS6) - so, you're only options are to either upgrade Photoshop or find a non-content-aware solution.

Comment: Correct. You will have to stick to old fashioned cloning, OP.

Comment: Thanks Nir....I'll search for another non-content-aware solution

Comment: IMO it's more accurate if you just clone it...

Comment: What I do is paste a selection of similar background over the object, mask it in, so that what you are starting with is more similar, then do your cloning.

Answer (score 8):

Content Aware fill [was introduced in Photoshop CS5](http://www.adobe.com/hk_en/products/photoshop/content-aware-fill.html)  and is also available in an improved version of CS6.

CS4 can do a [content aware scaling](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/how-to-use-content-aware-scaling-in-photoshop-cs4/) but that is pretty much it.

Your CS3 version does therefore not even have that option. I would recommend you to either buy/upgrade CS5/6 or try without it by using [GIMP and the resynthesizer](http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh/resynthesizer) which is a free alternative.

Comment: I wasn't happy with the output quality from GIMP / resynthesizer, but for the price it's worth a look. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct this option not available on CS3. I haven't checked on CS5 or CS6 version but might be available on these please check from your side.

Comment: You can download a fresh copy of Adobe Phtoshop CS3 from [FileParrots](https://fileparrots.blogspot.com/).